How to send log output to stdout using docker-compose run?
The existing question How to view log output using docker-compose run allows me to interactively view docker compose run logs. But for Gitlab CI/CD I need the output from all involved containers on stdout.
A simple workaround would appear to be docker log --follow & beforehand but in that case the CI/CD pipeline does not terminate, which causes it to fail with a timeout.
As a minimal example, using:
CMD ['echo', 'Hello, World']

in a Dockerfile, run that with docker compose run HelloWorld.
Desired output: "Hello, World"
Current output: ""

You mean you want the logs from the containers than ran in the network after the process is complete? Just use docker compose logs, e.g. https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/tech-products-demo/blob/9078480090ba185d847f90adcf9d60b27c27aad4/.github/workflows/push.yml#L49-L53 (also the top answer on the linked question).

@jonrsharpe: Nope, that doesn't work. That won't run when a previous command fails, but that is when you need the logs the most. It also does not work when you have a timeout in a previous command.

It does run when a previous command fails, that's the point of line 50 - I assume GitLab CI has something similar. If you've tried things that don't work, though, put a [mre] in the question.

@jonrsharpe: Gitlab CI does have an after-script: but the documentation explicitly warns that after a failure it probably does not run.

Note reproducible - the argument to docker compose run is a service name, which needs a definition. Also this is likely to depend at least partly on what and how you're doing it in GitLab.

The workaround  I've found is to move the entire test to a shell script, gitlab-ci-client.sh. This script is the only thing called by Gitlab CI/CD.
Using the HelloWorld container example from the question, that gives me
#! /bin/bash
# Between docker compose and gitlab ci yaml nonsense, logging is hard.
# This shell script avoids the need to define tests in yaml,
# and the log tailing is under process control
COMPOSE="docker compose -f docker-compose.tests.yml -f docker-compose.gitlab.yml"

# Preparation stage
$COMPOSE logs --tail 0 --follow &
$COMPOSE build

echo -e "\e[32mDocker images built, starting tests...\e[0m"

EXIT=0

$COMPOSE run HelloWorld || EXIT=1

if [ $EXIT -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo -e "\e[32mTests passed\e[0m"
else
  echo -e "\e[33;1mTests failed, result=${EXIT}\e[0m"
fi

# Cleanup. You can't do this from Gitlab CI/CD, and without this cleanup the CI/CD pipeline hangs
$COMPOSE down
pkill -P $$
echo -e "\e[32mCleanup finished\e[0m"
exit $EXIT


It works as specified:
services:
  test:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: ["echo",  "Hello, World!"]

> docker compose run test > test.txt
> cat test.txt
"Hello, World!"

